# Change PendingIntent action at run time when click on notification

Tags: android, android-activity, push-notification, android-pendingintent

I have integrated Push Notification in the app, I am working on rite now, what i am doing is setting the pendingintent to currentTopActivity class of the app if the app is in foreground state, if app is in background state then setting HomeActivity class as default class to open HomeActivity on notification click. I am setting notification `setAutoCancel(fasle);` which make the notification to remain in notification area.

The problem is: if I got the notification and I am on the
`ThirdActivity.class` then it sets `ThirdActivity.class` in
PendingIntent to be open on notification click at first time now if
the second time user clicks on notification then it should not open
the `ThirdActivity` instead it should open `HomeActivity` when user
clicks on notification second time.

Setting class where classString is fetched depending on the state of the app as described earlier:

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent();
        notificationIntent.setClassName(context, classString);
```

So how can I change the pendingIntent at run time after user have clicked it first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the pending intent to [send a broadcast](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getBroadcast(android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int)). Then you receive it in a `<receiver>` and from that receiver you choose which activity to launch depending on the state.